# Dataframes of different lengths

Tags: r, time-series, dataframe

I'm looking at the time series of the DJIA and FSTE100 but they are not of the same length because of trading days. How can I fix this in R?

I saw a code snippet and I tried to adapt it must my data like this:

```
zz <- merge(ftse100$Date, djia$Close, all = TRUE)
zz[is.na(zz)] <- 0
View(zz)
```

But it didn't give me the result that I want, it was duplicating the rows, so I tried to do it myself:

```
z<-setdiff(ftse100$Date,djia$Date)
print(length(z))

for (i in 1:length(z) )  {
    index = match(c(z[i]), ftse100$Date)
    ftse100 <- ftse100[-c(index),]
}
print(NROW(ftse100))
```

But I would have to do this to all the dataframes and it was getting over complicated. Is there a way to remove the dates that aren't in every data-frame?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might do what you want:

```
set.seed(2)
stocksA <- data.frame(Date=sample(1:10, 7), price=rnorm(7))
stocksB <- data.frame(Date=sample(1:10, 7), price=rnorm(7))
stocksC <- data.frame(Date=sample(1:10, 7), price=rnorm(7))
sharedDates <- intersect(intersect(stocksA$Date, stocksB$Date), stocksC$Date)
relevantA <- stocksA[stocksA$Date %in% sharedDates, ]
relevantA
```

This gives me:

```
  Date      price
1    2  0.9678839
2    7  0.1256203
6    8 -0.7526655
```

You could of course leverage some loops if you need to do it for lots of datasets...